# showing differences in chart lines C#

Tags: c#, charts

so using windows forms chart it is possible to create different style lines, such as dashed or dotted, like this:

```
chart1.Series["series1"].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
```

What my issue is, is that these look like solid lines in my graph, because of how many data points there are in my graph (1024). The problem is that the dashes are grouped so close together it is impossible to discriminate from a solid line without zooming in. Is there a way to fix this without getting rid of some data points? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Did you try to increase your x and y axis scales?

Comment: I'd like to be able to do it without having a bunch of extra space on the ends of my graph, but increasing the scales doesn't seem to solve the issue, it just makes it worse as there is now a tighter visual area where all the points are being condensed into.

Comment: Don't think it's possible. You could try using `ChartDashStyle.Dot` instead, though that may not work. The other option would be to prune your data so there are fewer points.